# secondary edit pages for user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a settings tab which links to the user to edit_user_registrations_path corresponding to the devise/registrations/edit.html.erb page.

I've created another page under devise/registrations called edit_account.html.erb and I'd like this to allow the user to edit additional settings like Twitter and any other social networks that allow it.

My route:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "edit/edit_account", :to => "devise/registrations#edit_account"
end
```

error:

```
undefined method model_name error:: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

Basically, the form_for resource in the secondary edit page is causing an error. What should I change that too to work with the new route?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one instead to add a new action to registrations controller

```
devise_for :users do
  get "edit/edit_account", :to => "devise/registrations#edit_account", :as => "account_registration"
end
```

But it would be better if you create a new controller named `users_controller.rb` and add the required action in it

Comment: Thanks TSB, and would that still work as a sub edit page of a devise edit page?